# How to use htaccess to redirect directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is to use `.htaccess` to redirect directories, but not files. As an example, I want `mydomain.com/Archive/Documents` to be redirected to `mydomain.com/Browser/Archive/Documents`, but I **do not** want `mydomain.com/Archive/Documents/File.docx` to be redirected at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in your root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#if /archive/dir exists

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archive/$1 -d
#rewrite /archive/dir to /browser/archive/dir
RewriteRule ^archive/(.+)$ /browser/archive/$1 [L]
```

This internally maps the request.
If you want to redirect the request ,just add a R flag to the rule.